# Does std::is_unsigned imply std::is_integral

Tags: c++, type-traits

If I need a type that satisfy `std::is_unsigned` and `std::is_integral`, do I have to check both or only `std::is_unsigned`?

Comment: Yes, `is_unsigned` implies `is_integral`. Did you check the [manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes but I didn't see why constant value equal true if T(0) < T(-1) implies integral type, but now I am sure then thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

cppreference has this line for `is_unsigned` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned):

> this results in true for the unsigned integer types and the type bool and in false for the signed integer types and the floating-point types.
>   For any other type, value is false.

so if `is_unsigned` is `true`, then `is_integral` will as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned).

Just keep in mind that this doesn't work everywhere, and is only guaranteed for native types. I had an issue with `boost::multiprecision` giving wrong results for integers. The best way to do this is with `numeric_limits`:

```
std::numeric_limits<MyIntType>::is_signed
```